# Python Selenium - How can I get timedate inside of class?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

This is the HTML code (LinkedIn company's job page, linkedin.com/yourcompany/jobs/)

```html
<li id="ember623" class="ember-view   jobs-search-results__list-item occludable-update p0 relative scaffold-layout__list-item

 [...]
   
                ">
              <time datetime="2022-09-20">
                2 days ago

<!---->              </time>
            </li>
          
[...]
        
    </li>
```

I'm trying to access the date in the datetime attribute by using CLASS_NAME.

When I search using XPATH, it works, and I get the date: '2022-09-20'

```
    A = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//time")
    A[index].get_attribute("datetime")
```

When I search for the date using class_name, like so:

```
    A = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"occludable-update")
    A[index].get_attribute("datetime")
```

It returns empty.

But if I write:

```
    A = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"occludable-update")
    A[index].text
```

I get: '2 days ago'

How can I get the date, and not the text, by using By.CLASS_NAME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#if only 1 time element:
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"time").get_attribute("datetime") #return '2022-09-20'

browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"time").text #return '2 days ago'

#if only many time element:
[i.get_attribute("datetime") for i in browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"time").get_attribute("datetime")]
#return ['2022-09-20', ...]


[i.text for i in browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"time").get_attribute("datetime")]
# returns ['2 days ago', ...]
```

if return empty, try using wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "time"))).text
```

Comment: Sorry, (By.CLASS_NAME,"time") returns empty

Comment: use ```WebDriverWait```, i updated my answer

Comment: Thank you. So the datetime attribute is only accessible if I look specifically for the "time" tag?

Comment: @michal_levin yes